# Process List Async from CompletableFuture

Tags: completable-future

I have one method that return a `CompletableFuture<List<Object>>` .

And my goal is call a `void method()` for each element of this CompletableFuture.

But I'd like to do this in an asynchronous way so I don't have to wait for the List that comes from CompletableFuture. In short, I'd like to build the list asynchronously (as I'm doing now) but take advantage of that and execute the `void method()` as well at the same time to take advantage of better performance.

**As is**

1. Construct a List Async
2. Iterate the list and run async `void method()`

**To be**

3. Create a `CompletableFuture<List>` and **for each item processed/completed** run `void method()` async (like reactive way)

So I think I should use `thenCombine` or I'm wrong ?

What is the best way ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you write the method that returns `CompletableFuture<List<Object>>`, or is it a library? The current signature means you must delay processing until *all* the items are available. `List<CompletableFuture<Object>>` would support the approach you desire.

Comment: I have two modules (module1 and module2) . 
The module2 (library) has a method that return a `List<Object>`and inside runs a `supplyAsync` (3rd party Java API) to construct it.
The module1 call module2 but I when receive all List<Objects> I want to iterate this list with a `runAsync`void computation and return finally after all computations completed as well.

Comment: Yes, the module2's method in written by me using a `supplyAsync`and return a List<Object>